# Why can't I get my chunks of pdf into the mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, upload

So, here is the code I'm trying to use to break up a big pdf file into chunks and store it in my database.  Is there any reason why it isn't working.  I've worked all day to figure it out and have gone in circles a bunch.  Would appreciate any help!  Thanks!

```
<?
$username="something";
$password="something";
$database="something";

mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to select database");

$STARTFILE = 1;
$ONFILE = "file" . $STARTFILE;

while (isset($HTTP_POST_FILES["$ONFILE"])) {

// Try!
$SrcPathFile = $HTTP_POST_FILES["$ONFILE"]["tmp_name"];
$SrcFileType = $HTTP_POST_FILES["$ONFILE"]["type"];
$DstFileName = $HTTP_POST_FILES["$ONFILE"]["name"];

clearstatcache();
$time = filemtime($SrcPathFile);
$storedate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time);

// File Processing
if (file_exists($SrcPathFile)) {

// Insert into file table
$SQL  = "insert into tbldocuments(Type,Description,Size,DateTime) values ('";
$SQL .= $SrcFileType . "', '" . $DstFileName . "', " . filesize($SrcPathFile);
$SQL .= ", '" . $storedate . "')";

if (!$RES = mysql_query($SQL, $linkid)) {
  die("Failure on insert to file table!");
}

$fileid = mysql_insert_id($linkid);

// Insert into the filedata table
$fp = fopen($SrcPathFile, "rb");
while (!feof($fp)) {

  // Make the data mysql insert safe
  $binarydata = addslashes(fread($fp, 65535));

  $SQL = "insert into tblDocumentChunks (documentId,chunkData) values (";
  $SQL .= $fileid . ", '" . $binarydata . "')";

  if (!mysql_query($SQL, $linkid)) {
    die("Failure to insert binary inode data row!");
  }
}

fclose($fp);
}

$STARTFILE ++;
$ONFILE = "file" . $STARTFILE;
}

echo "Upload Complete";
?>
```

Comment: What's the error?  What's not working?

Comment: You ought to insert with each chunk some indication of its order. But why break it into chunks at all?  Use `MEDIUMBLOB` or `LONGBLOB` data types to hold up to 16MiB and 4GiB respectively.  I'm also not convinced that PHP will gracefully concatenate arbitrary binary data with a string (although on this I could well be wrong).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `$HTTP_POST_FILES` has been deprecated for quite a while. Use `$_FILES` instead.

Second, you're declaring a variable `$ONFILE`, but you're not referencing it in the array.

Try removing the quotes (`$ONFILE` instead of `"$ONFILE"`)

Comment: The quotes aren't affecting anything: [codepad example](http://codepad.org/CemSIykv)